# How to temporarily run a secondary SSH server on a separate port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

How do you run an SSH daemon on a different port other than the standard 22?

I screwed up something with my SSH configuration on a cloud VM, so that now SSH always prompts me for a password. My early attempts to fix this locked me out, forcing me to umount the disk, mount it inside a working VM, and fix the files to a known working state. However, it's still forcing me to enter a password.

I'd like to update my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart the main ssh daemon, which I can test against, while still having another one running, using the old configuration, that I can use to revert the configuration in case the first one locks me out. How would I do this, specifically on Ubuntu?

Comment: Note that stopping `sshd` does not kill any established connections so you won't be locked out if you have an existing session opened prior to making changes.

Comment: Snapshot the virtual machine then if you need to revert the changes you can do it by rebooting from the image.

Comment: `"configuration on a cloud VM"` - Then just use the console they give you - no 2nd SSH needed. The console is there specifically for when you lock yourself out.

Answer (score 19):

You didn't mention an Ubuntu version, so I am not sure which init system you are running.

If systemd, you may have a file `/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service`.  Which you could make a copy of as `/etc/systemd/system/sshd_alt.service`.  Then adjust the `ExecStart` line and add a `-p 22000` or something.  After that do `systemctl enable sshd_alt` and `systemctl start sshd_alt`.   You could also point at a completely different configuration file.

You could also just manually start a copy in screen or something if this is just a one time thing.  Just start screen and do something like `/usr/sbin/sshd -D  -p 22200`.  You will start a spare sshd daemon until you can re-attach to that screen and kill the process.

Or like @EEAA said.  Simply don't disconnect, use a second session to test that you can reconnect.

Answer (score 13):

You can start an sshd on an alternate port with this command:

```
sshd -p 12345
```

Replace 12345 by your favorite port number. If `sshd` is not in your `PATH`, you may need to use the full pathname in the command, e.g. `/usr/sbin/sshd`.

Comment: Regardless of path, you need /usr/sbin/sshd, otherwise you just get error: sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path

Comment: /usr/sbin/sshd -p12345 -f path_to_working_cfg.file

Comment: @Lenne: I've never hit that issue.

Comment: @R.. This comes from OpenSSH v 3.9 and forwards. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109383/21109 for more info.

Comment: How ridiculous. They could just assume the one in the path is right if it was executed without an absolute path, and/or use `/proc/self/exe` if available.

Comment: `sudo $(which sshd) -p 12345`

Answer (score 9):

Just leave one SSH session active and use another to make your configuration changes. Your original session will remain connected and available to revert changes if your config changes break something.

Comment: When doing this I'll open a spare session, just in case something happens to the first one before I have the new configuration working. It's such simple insurance against having to rescue the VM when you accidentally close your shell because your had the wrong window focussed when you hit `cmd-w` or `ctrl-f4`.